# Cakephp 3 rendering view inside controller

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I know that it seems bad practice to render a view within a controller and then use a helper from controller. But I have one exception in our works. In cakephp 2 it was like this:

```
class MyController extends Controller {
    ...
    public function myFunction() {
        $this->set('pagesArray', $pagesArray);
        $this->set('sitemapType', $sitemapType);

        $view = new View($this);
        $viewdata = $view->render('my_function');
        file_put_contents($path, $viewdata);
        ...
        $myData = $view->Myhelper->getData();
    }
    ...
}
```

Is this possible in cakephp 3 ?

Comment: Every thing is possible. Are you trying to get view using ajax?

Comment: No this is not an ajax request. Does it make a difference except params-requested check.

Answer (score 1):

Use View Cells, they were designed with this kind of use case in mind:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html

Otherwise you can just call `$response = $this->render()` and then save the result in a file:

```
file_put_contents($path, $response->body());
```

Comment: Thanks. `$this->render()` works from controller. But is it possible to call a helper method from controller. It was possible in cakephp 2. Edited question.

Comment: Also, is it possible to reach request parameters within view file? For example I make this `$Mains = new MainsController();
$response = $Mains->render('index','default');` And inside the `index.ctp` , I check for `$this->request->params['controller']` parameter. But it seems like, when I try to reach `request` object from view file, it is empty. (In normal conditions request object is ok, but in this case empty)

Comment: Creating an empty controller and rendering a view that way is a bad idea, therefore you get unexpected results.

Answer (score -2):

```
$view = new View(new Request(), new Response());
$viewdata = $view->render('my_function);
```